# How to pass data from a component to a service, in order to make a new http request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i pass a string value from my app.component to my service, so i can open a new URL there based on this data, but for some reason, i'm getting a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')" error, why is that?

on my app.component.ts i have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { searchMoviesService } from './services/buscar-todos-produtos.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    movie1: any;
    movie1Data: any;

    constructor(private searchMoviesService: searchMoviesService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.searchMoviesService.getData().subscribe((searchProdutos: any) => {
            this.movie1 = searchProdutos.films[1];
        })
        this.searchMovie();
    }

    searchMovie() {
        this.searchMoviesService.searchMovie(this.movie1).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.movie1Data = data;
        });
    }
}
```

and my service I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// import { buscarProdutos } from '../Models/buscarProdutos';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class searchMoviesService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData() {
        return this.http.get<any[]>('https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/?format=json');
    }

    searchMovie(data: string) {
        console.log(data);
        return this.http.get<string[]>(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in passing a string param to the service, that part of the code looks fine.

In this snippet:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchMoviesService.getData().subscribe((searchProdutos: any) => {
      this.movie1 = searchProdutos.films[1];
    })
    this.searchMovie();
}
```

In subscribing to `getData()` the assigning of the value to `this.movie1` is asynchronous.

In other words the program execution does not wait for the value to return from that call you make. Thus it will go on and execute `this.searchMovie()` while the value is not yet assigned and thus `undefined`.

The console is just telling you that `undefined` has no function `toLowerCase`, which (although true) is not very helpful. But when something is undefined, **timing issues** is one of the possibilities that should jump to mind.

One thing you could do is:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchMoviesService.getData().subscribe((searchProdutos: any) => {
      this.movie1 = searchProdutos.films[1];
      this.searchMovie();
    })
}
```

But there are other solutions you can try out, once you get this concept.